# JavaScript/JSON- Sending a POST request to database via JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json, url

I need to send a post request to this URL.

```
localhost:8080/customer/add?firstName=STRING&lastName=STRING&custPhone=STRING&custEmail=STRING&notificationPreference=INTEGER
```

The words in capital are variables that will hold user input.

An example of a URL that adds customer information to the data is.

```
localhost:8080/customer/add?firstName=Linx&lastName=Blek&custPhone=5126984758&custEmail=blek@gmail.com&notificationPreference=3
```

This adds customer's first name, last name, email, phone number, and notification preference.

This is my JavaScript code

```
function addCustomer() {

   var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
   var lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
   var phoneNum = document.getElementById("phone").value;
   var emailAddress = document.getElementById("email").value;   
   var notifications = document.getElementById("notification").value;


   var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

   var url = "localhost:8080/customer/add?";

   request.open("POST", url, true);

   request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

   request.onreadystatechange = function () 
   { 
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) 
    {
        var json = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        console.log(json.firstName + ", " + json.&lastName + ", " + json.&custPhone+ ", " + json.&custEmail + ", " + json.&notificationPreference);
    }
}

   var parameters = JSON.stringify({"firstName=":firstName,"&lastName=":lastName,"&custPhone=":phoneNum,"&custEmail=":emailAddress,"&notificationPreference=":notifications});




   request.send(parameters);





}​​
</script>
```

It takes user input from HTML fields, and opens a POST request, and sends a request to the URL with customer input appended to the URL (as shown below). However, currently this isn't working- what am I doing wrong?

JSON Object

```
  {
        "custID": 100002,
        "custEmail": "josephine_darakjy@darakjy.org",
        "custPhone": "8102929388",
        "firstName": "Josephine",
        "lastName": "Darakjy",
        "notificationPreference": 1
    },
```

Comment: Invalid JSON in `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: @PHPglue You don't need JSON before you stringify the object as JSON....  But yes, that line is insanity.

Comment: @PHPglue Can you explain what's going wrong in it? I'll add an example of JSON object in the main post

Comment: @Brad As well, if you can explain what's wrong with the line

Comment: `var parameters = JSON.stringify({"firstName=":firstName,"&lastName=":lastName,"&custPhone=":phoneNum,"&custEmail=":emailAddress,"&notificationPreference=":notifications});` should probably be `var parameters = JSON.stringify({firstName:firstName, lastName:lastName, custPhone:phoneNum, custEmail:emailAddress, notificationPreference:notifications});`

Comment: @PHPglue No change unfortunately,  still isn't working :/    I had the "&" in the JSON stringify because if you see the localhost URL example I had above, the "&" was a part of it

Comment: Change `var url = "localhost:8080/customer/add?";` to `var url = 'customer/add';`.